# How to change left and top of SVG element using JS?

Tags: svg

I'm creating a SVG line using JS:

```
function createEdge(){
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    var svgLine = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");

    svgLine.setAttribute('x1', '50');
    svgLine.setAttribute('y1', '50');
    svgLine.setAttribute('x2', '200');
    svgLine.setAttribute('y2', '200');
    svgLine.setAttribute('stroke', 'blue');
    svg.setAttribute('position', 'relative');

    svg.appendChild(svgLine);
    document.body.appendChild(svg);

    var bbox=svg.childNodes[0].getBBox();
    svg.setAttribute("width", bbox.width + "px");
    svg.setAttribute("height",bbox.height + "px");
}
```

Adjusting the size of the parent element is working fine.
But with the top and left it's not.

I've tried svg.setAttribute("viewBox", ...) and svg.setAttribute( "x", ...), but it didn't work.

As a result I have SVG parent element and line element with different coordinates:

[image]

How can I change the coordinates of the parent SVG element (equal to the line coords)?
Thanks!

UPD: If I use viewBox like this

```
svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "50 50 200 200");
```

it's not moving the SVG to x=50 y=50 as expected,

instead it's moving both the SVG and line element to x = 0 y = 0

[image]

What I'm expecting to get:

[image]

Comment: In this case you need to use `viewBox="50 50 150 150"`  i.e. viewBox="x1 y1 x2-x1 y2-y1"

Comment: it's not working as expected. See the UPD above

Comment: This means that I don't understand your question. Please try `viewBox="0 0 250 250"` Maybe this is what you are expecting

Comment: ok, but what if I want to put the line in the right bottom corner? Does it mean that viewBox will be same size as the window?

Comment: viewBox="0 0 200 200"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm curious about the use case, but as I understand it you would like to do the following. The position of the SVG done using CSS (or the style attribute). To move all the child nodes to the SVG I create a group (`<g>`) that I transform/translate in the opposite direction according the the relative position (and then remove the original elements/the line).

```js
createEdge();

function createEdge(){
    var svg = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "svg");
    var svgLine = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "line");

    svgLine.setAttribute('x1', '50');
    svgLine.setAttribute('y1', '50');
    svgLine.setAttribute('x2', '200');
    svgLine.setAttribute('y2', '200');
    svgLine.setAttribute('stroke', 'blue');
    svg.style.position = 'relative';

    svg.appendChild(svgLine);
    document.body.appendChild(svg);

    var bbox=svg.getBBox();
    svg.setAttribute("width", bbox.width);
    svg.setAttribute("height",bbox.height);
    svg.style.left = bbox.x + 'px';
    svg.style.top = bbox.y + 'px';
    var group = document.createElementNS("http://www.w3.org/2000/svg", "g");
    group.setAttribute('transform', `translate(-${bbox.x} -${bbox.y})`);
    svg.childNodes.forEach(elm => {
      group.append(elm.cloneNode(true));
    });
    svg.innerHTML = '';
    svg.append(group);
}
```

Comment: Meanwhile I found another way.  I've made one SVG parent tag: svg.setAttribute("viewBox", "0 0 2000 1000"). Then added all the figures to it as its child nodes. What do you think about it?

Comment: @AntonAntonoff I guess that sounds fine. I still struggle with the use case, but as long as it works.